# Failing wait for request in Cypress

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress

I'm wrote wait on 3 different requests on my automated test, but each time I run the test, the wait functions on one of the requests.

```
 cy
        .intercept('POST', '**/api/Availability')
        .as('availabilecheck');
    cy
        .wait('@availabilecheck')
        .its('response.statusCode')
        .should('eq', 200)
```

////////////////////////////////////////

```
        cy
    .intercept('POST','**/api/Availability/GetPrice')
    .as('getpricecheck');
cy
    .wait('@getpricecheck')
    .its('response.statusCode')
    .should('eq', 200);
```

////////////////////////////

```
 cy.intercept('POST','**/api/Member/Find')
        .as('memberresponse')
    cy.wait('@memberresponse')
```

I wrote the above code for 3 different requests but each time I run the test, one of the requests actually waits and the other 2 fails.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

**The order of commands matters**. In my case I had to move the `cy.intercept()` command before the action that performed the `request`

```
//the intercept comes first
cy.intercept("POST", "**/api/user/login").as("loginResponse");

//this performs POST request in my case, comes second
cy.get('button[type="submit"]').should("not.be.disabled").click();

//thirdly comes the wait
cy.wait("@loginResponse").its("response.statusCode").should("eq", 200);
```

Comment: The original poster already had their intercept commands before the requests were made so this answer doesn't seem to make sense to me?

Comment: The original poster lacks any requests between intercepting and waiting if I am not mistaken and see correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If the endpoints you are intercepting are not different, then Cypress will only take the first one and discard any subsequent ones. Make sure that the text that you are matching the url against is different for each request.

Comment: Basically I have 2 requests '**/api/Availability' and '**/api/Availability/GetPrice' . So are you saying that it's because of the similarity of these two requests?

Comment: Since you are using the minimatch approach, refer to the minimatch tip on this page: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Matching-URL

Comment: I don't think that is my issue here, I've tried other ways to write the url and it still didn't work.

Comment: Can you share the code for all of the waits that you’re doing?

Comment: I just updated the question and added the other waits

Comment: I tried to verify that it was a minimatch issue and it isn't, so my answer is invalid. I'll try to take another look at the problem and see if I can come up with another theory. In the meantime, is there a way that you can provide a minimum reproducible example for the exact issue you're having?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't think I can provide that. but I get this error : "Timed out retrying after 20000ms: cy.wait() timed out waiting 20000ms for the 1st request to the route: availabilecheck. No request ever occurred."

Comment: That makes it sound like the request was never made by the application. If you check the network tab of your dev tools while the application is being tested then you’ll be able to verify whether or not the request is being made by your application.

Comment: The request is made and it successfully passed with 200 status code. that is the weird part for me.

Comment: A new version of cypress was released a few days ago that makes substantial changes to cy.intercept. Maybe upgrade to that and see if it solves your problem.